# Using separate() from tidyr to separate letter code into 4 variables in r

Tags: r, tidyr

I have data on fish ID and the ID variable is made up of a four letter code, first letter for paternity, second for maternity, third for treatment, fourth for the individual. A single observation may look like this `BBRG`.

This data is as a single variable and I need to split these letters into separate columns, since there is nothing separating them I wasn't sure what to place in the `sep=` argument in `separate`.

Example data:

```
test.dataframe <- data.frame(observation = c(1:10),
                             VIE.Code = c("BBRG", "BRBR", "PPWG", "RRWW",
                                          "WRWR", "BBBP", "PBPB", "PPGW",
                                          "RWRW", "BGBG"))
```

Comment: FYI, `separate` is a `tidyr` function, not a `dplyr` one. I've edited accordingly

Comment: Also, it's very difficult to help well without a [reproducible question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). That includes posting a representative sample of data, the code you've tried that hasn't worked, and the desired outcome. Otherwise, we're kind of in the dark about what's going on.

Comment: You can edit your question to put code there, which is much easier to read and format than in comments

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, I understand and I've attached some code that I used to create a similar but simple data frame that I'm trying to test things on. 
`
test.dataframe <- data.frame(observation = c(1:10), VIE.Code = c("BBRG", "BRBR", "PPWG", "RRWW", "WRWR", "BBBP", "PBPB", "PPGW", "RWRW", "BGBG")) 
`
Apologies, I'm quite new to r and all this

Comment: I've tried to put that as code by putting it in backticks (as it says in the markdown help) but it's not worked

Comment: You can edit the question to include code; it's much easier to format and read there than in comments.

Answer (score 1):

We can use a regex lookaround

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
  separate(ID, into = c("paternity", "maternity", "treatment", "individual"), 
             sep="(?<=[A-Z])")
```

Or specify the `sep` as the location index

```
df1 %>%
  separate(ID, into = c("paternity", "maternity", "treatment", "individual"),
          sep= c(1, 2, 3))
```

---

A `base R` method would be to split

```
do.call(rbind, strsplit(df1$ID, ""))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c("BBRG", "BBGR"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Hi there, that's a really good sounding method but I've tried it on my dataset and get the error

Error in UseMethod("separate_") : 
  no applicable method for 'separate_' applied to an object of class "factor"

is my ID variable in the wrong format?

Comment: @T.Miller  It should work for `factor` as well.  If there is an issue try `df1 %>% mutate(ID = as.character(ID)) %>% separate(ID, ..`